# Exact definition of Fourier transform on L^p and some calculation

Tags: fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis, schwartz-space

I'm interested in the definition of Fourier transform of a function $ f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^d) $, where $ p \in [1, \infty] $ and $ d \in \mathbb{N} $ is the dimension.

The way I understand is that one treats $ f $ as a tempered distribution $ \Lambda_f $, where
$$
\Lambda_f h = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x) h(x) \, \mathrm{d} x \, .
$$
The Fourier transform on the tempered distributions space $ \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}) $ is then given by $ (\mathcal{F} \Lambda)(h) = \Lambda (\mathcal{F} h) $.
This allows us to calculate the Fourier transform of e.g. Dirac distribution, since
$$
(\mathcal{F} \delta)(h) = \delta(\mathcal{F} h) = (\mathcal{F} h)(0) 
= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} h(\xi) \exp(- 2 \pi i \langle 0, \xi\rangle) \, \mathrm{d} \xi = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} h(\xi) \, \mathrm{d} \xi \, ,
$$
so in fact $ \mathcal{F} \delta = 1 $ (the constant function).
However, let's suppose that I want to calculate the Fourier transform of the function $ f \equiv 1 $ which from what I understand is again the Dirac delta distribution. As far as I know, $ \mathcal{F} f = \mathcal{F} \Lambda_f $ (is this wrong?), but I cannot show that this in fact yields $ \mathcal{F} f = \delta $.

The question I suppose is where is my reasoning faulty and how to find the Fourier transform of $ f \equiv 1 $.

Comment: There are no problems for $1\le p\le 2,$ as the Fourier transform maps $L^p$ into $L^q$ where $q$ is the conjugate exponent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re correct that the Fourier transform of an $L^p$ function is the Fourier transform of the tempered distribution induced by that function.

The function $f=1$ induces the functional $\Lambda(h) = \int h(x)dx$, i.e. the integration functional, acting on Schwarz functions. By definition, the Fourier transform of $\Lambda$ is precisely the functional $\mathcal{F}\Lambda$ which acts on Schwarz functions via $\mathcal{F}\Lambda(h) = \Lambda(\mathcal{F}h)$. But $\Lambda(\mathcal{F}h) $ is the integral of $\mathcal{F}h$, which is in fact $(\mathcal{F}\mathcal{F} h)(0)$. However, applying the Fourier transform twice is just reflection $h(x)\mapsto h(-x)$ (possibly with some constants depending on your definition) but since we’re evaluating at zero, this yields $h(0)$.

Comment: That's funny, because I got the the $ (\mathcal{F}\mathcal{F}h)(0) $ part, but then just got lost into calculation. Thank you!